# Toggling background color of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Title, my only problem is that when I've created all elements on my page, and clicked all of them, my page looks like a chess board.

I can only "toggle" the background color of half too. So it's not only that they don't change color on the first click, they don't change at all.

This is my Javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var itemContainer = document.createElement("div" + i);
    itemContainer.id = "div" + i;
    itemContainer.className = "item";
    itemContainer.innerHTML = "Hello!";

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $('div' + i).click(function() {
            if (this.className == "item") {
                this.className = "itemselected";
            } else {
                this.className = "item";
            }
        });
    }

    document.getElementById("page").appendChild(itemContainer);
}
```

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfr496p6/2/) for you who want it.

I've seen a few other questions about how to toggle the color of backgrounds, but none of them have the same problem as me.

Comment: Why do you have the c# tag here :)?

Comment: Oops, removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You inserted your second loop into the first one, every second `i` got skipped. And probably was able to change your divs up to `i=18`

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfr496p6/7/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var itemContainer = document.createElement("div" + i);
    itemContainer.id = "div" + i;
    itemContainer.className = "item";
    itemContainer.innerHTML = "Hello!";

    document.getElementById("page").appendChild(itemContainer);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('div' + i).click(function() {
        if (this.className == "item") {
            this.className = "itemselected";
        } else {
            this.className = "item";
        }
    });
}
```

Edit: You could simply put the content of your second loop into the first loop, to simplify your code a bit.

Comment: That did the trick for me. Exactly what I wanted and with an explanation and not only lines of code, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You were close, missing "#" of id element

```
$('div' + i).click(function() {


$('#div' + i).click(function() {
```

and you have inserted the second loop inside first one

https://jsfiddle.net/snbtchph/

Comment: Are you sure that works? It doesn't work for me, not even in your fiddle.

Comment: I'm am, try to click on first hello, it should become green

Comment: Yeah, but that's not what the problem is. That worked in my fiddle too. If you read my question again, the problem is that only the 1st, 3rd, 5th and so on becomes green, but not the 2nd, 4th and 6th...

Comment: Ok fix it. You have inserted the second loop inside first one

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2 loops try that

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var itemContainer = document.createElement("div");
  itemContainer.id = "div" + i;
  itemContainer.className = "item";
  itemContainer.innerHTML = "Hello!";
  document.getElementById("page").appendChild(itemContainer);

    $('#div' + i).click(function() {
    alert("here");
      if (this.className == "item") {
        this.className = "itemselected";
      } else {
        this.className = "item";
      }
    });
}
```

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/xfr496p6/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector at line 8 of your JavaScript is missing the `#` so the jQuery is looking for `<div0>, <div1>, <div2>...`, and, your line 2 of JavaScript is `var itemContainer = document.createElement("div" + i);` which actual creating elements `div0, div1...`.

And since you are using jQuery , I have also revised some code to use it instead of native JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/xfr496p6/5/

I have also added css `.item { display: inline-block; }` to makes the elements placed in a row.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code:

`var itemContainer = document.createElement("div" + i);`

- Creating non-existant elements like `<div1>` is impossible, remove the iterator.

`for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {`

- jQuery's `.click()` doesn't need a for loop, but adds the event listener to every case, this is not needed.

`document.getElementById("page").appendChild(itemContainer);`

- Apply this directly in after the `.innerHTML`

In addition, you seem to randomly use ES6, jQuery, and VanillaJS through your entire codebase, I'd like to advise you to be consistant with how you write your applications.

I've updated your fiddle with the working changes.
https://jsfiddle.net/xfr496p6/8/

Updated javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var itemContainer = document.createElement("div");
    itemContainer.id = "div" + i;
    itemContainer.className = "item";
    itemContainer.innerHTML = "Hello!" + i;
    document.getElementById("page").appendChild(itemContainer);
}

$('div').click(function() {
    if (this.className == "item") {
        this.className = "itemselected";
    } else {
        this.className = "item";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have 2 nested loops?
try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var itemContainer = document.createElement("div" + i);
    itemContainer.id = "div" + i;
    itemContainer.className = "item";
    itemContainer.innerHTML = "Hello!";    

    document.getElementById("page").appendChild(itemContainer);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $('div' + i).click(function() {
            if (this.className == "item") {
                this.className = "itemselected";
            } else {
                this.className = "item";
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Moumit/xfr496p6/12/)**

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var itemContainer = document.createElement("div" + i);
  itemContainer.id = "div" + i;
  itemContainer.className = "item";
  itemContainer.innerHTML = "Hello!";

  $(itemContainer).click(function() {
    if (this.className == "item") {
      this.className = "itemselected";
    } else {
      this.className = "item";
    }
  });

  document.getElementById("page").appendChild(itemContainer);
}
```